# A question concerning the Schwartz space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, schwartz-space

Denote the Schwartz space by $\mathcal S(\mathbb{R})$. I want to show that $\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, $\|\cdot\|^{(n,k)} : \mathcal S(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ defined by 
$$\|f\|^{(n,k)} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |x^n f^{(k)}(x)|$$
is a norm on $\mathcal S(\mathbb{R})$ and therefore is a countably normed space.

I have never worked with this space before so I am a little unsure. The help would be appreciated!

Comment: I changed $||.||$ to $\|\cdot\|$ and $||f||$ to $\|f\|$. Both are standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @AlexR: No, on the Schwartz space, they are actual norms! But one has to work a bit to see that. At OP: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you know the necessary definitions?

Comment: @PhoemueX I noticed that by trying to come up with a counter-example. $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ is only metrisable, though if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I changed $J(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ and tidied the post a bit to (slightly) improve readability. $\mathcal S$ is the standard notation for schwartz space as far as I am aware.

Comment: What problems do you face? Can you show that $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert^{(n,k)}$ is a seminorm?

Comment: Hint: if $\|f\|^{(n,k)} = 0$, then (with a little bit of argument), you can conclude that $f^{(k)} \equiv 0$. What kind of functions are non-trivial solutions of the differential equation $f^{(k)} = 0$, and why wouldn't they be Schwartz (i.e. why must $f \equiv 0$)?

Comment: Sorry I have never even seen this space before but I was trying to be ambitious.

Answer (score 1):

The most difficult part of the exercise is to show that if $\|f\|^{(n,k)} =0$ for some $f\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$, then $f \equiv 0$.

For each $x$, we have $x^nf^{(k)}(x)=0$, hence for each $x\neq 0$, we get $f^{(k)}(x)=0$. Since $f^{(k)}$ is a continuous function, the equality $f^{(k)}(x)=0$ actually hold for each $x\in\mathbb R$. If $k=0$ we are done, and if $k\neq 0$, then defining $g:=f^{(k-1)}$, we have $g\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ and $g'=0$, hence $g(x)=c$ for some constant $c$. Since $g$ vanishes at infinity, we thus have $g(x)=f^{(k-1)}(x)=0$ for each $x$.

The proof can thus be completed by a clean induction.